# Find user location

Tags: java

I need to know how I can import a Map that will allow me to receive a users location, this should be simple since there are lot of sites that ask a user "allow site to track" location but I new to java.

I need the output to say something like 
User: 122312(Ip address)
location: 232 wood street (physical address on the imported map or google maps)

Comment: Assuming you want the location of the computer you're running your code on, you just need to find one of literally dozens of web sites that provide this information.  Then you need to learn how to have Python send a HTTP request and get back a response to get that information in a web page.  Then you need to learn how to parse that web page to pull the information you want out of the page.

Comment: There may also be an existing HTTP API that would let you get at this information more directly, without parsing HTML.  I don't know of one.  You could Google for that, or maybe someone else here knows of that.  Finally, maybe someone has written a python package that does this, via one of these two methods, but I don't know of one of those either.   Bottom line: This isn't a specific question about programming, so it probably doesn't belong here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

IP usually included in the request header but with that, you can only find out the country of the user (that might be wrong if the user is using the proxy).

If you want to capture the user location then you have to use client-side language such as javascript etc because you need to take user permission before capturing it if you are doing with the help of the browser. then the client side language will push you the latitude and longitude which will fulfill your purpose.

[Best Resource to explain you the everything in detail.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/)

Comment: @Steve No (Excluding Android), you'll get it at client side and java is not the one. another point is you cannot fetch the user location without his consent legally.

Comment: I get all of the ramifications of client/server, mobile computing, browsers, etc.  What I'm wondering is only if I run a Java program on my local Mac, can that code somehow (with permission or not) get geolocation information?  If my browser can do it, I'd think Java could do it somehow too.

Comment: I ask this partly because the OP didn't say if he's writing server code or client code in Java.  But I want to know for myself either way anyway.